# Event Popover for Google Calendar Events

Tags: fullcalendar

I'm trying to use the eventRender feature for multiple Google Calendars. I've got the calendars working, but when I add the eventRender code from the example I lose the calendars. I made a codepen here: https://codepen.io/christidtp/pen/MVrMdB

```
$(function() {

  $('#calendar').fullCalendar({

    themeSystem: 'bootstrap4',
    header: {
      left: 'prev,next today',
      center: 'title',
      right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay,listMonth'
    },

weekNumbers: false,
    eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
    googleCalendarApiKey: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
    eventSources: [
      {
        googleCalendarId: 'XXXX@group.calendar.google.com'
      },
      {
        googleCalendarId: 'XXXX@group.calendar.google.com',
        className: 'nice-event'
      }
    ],

eventRender: function(eventObj, $el) {
  $el.popover({
    title: eventObj.title,
    content: eventObj.description,
    trigger: 'hover',
    placement: 'top',
    container: 'body'
  });
},



 });

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there should not be a $ prefixing parameter el in your function eventRender...

Comment: I removed the $ and the calendar displays, but the popover does not. I'm not sure if it has to do with google calendar having a link on the event.

Comment: Looks like when i moved the trigger above the title it works.

Comment: "when i moved the trigger above the title it works"...they are just properties in an object, not linearly executed code...I highly doubt that's the real reason. Perhaps you changed something else at the same time. But at least it's working.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.  From the docs for the event object (https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-object):

> Non-standard Fields
>
> In addition to the fields above, you may also include your own non-standard fields in each Event Object. FullCalendar will not modify or delete these fields. For example, developers often include a description field for use in callbacks such as eventRender.

If the google calendar event doesn't have a description, then that field is undefined and will cause a silent error, most likely because it's in the callback.

Here is my solution.   I don't know anything about javascript so I'd be curious if there were a cleaner way to safely get a property as in this case.

```
eventRender: function(eventObj, el) {
  if (eventObj.description === undefined) {
    eventObj.description = "";
  } 
  $(el).popover({
    trigger: 'hover',
    title: eventObj.title,
    content: eventObj.description,
    placement: 'top',
    container: 'body'
  });
}
```

Comment: That did work, however when the calendar item has a description it continually flickers. So not sure what that's about. I didn't want to use a plugin, but since this will be a WordPress site i've opted to use the simplecalendar.io plugin to make life easier.

Comment: Hmm, I don't know about the flicker.  Works perfectly fine for me.  Maybe it's client side for you.  Something with the browser?  Oh well.